# Series LCR experiment

Tags: ac, oscillator, capacitance, inductance

i am doing a series LCR experiment for measuring the resonant frequency taking,
R= 100 ohm; L= 40mH; C=0.1uF. I am using a 10KHz audio oscillator having 10V p-p as the input.

I have fixed the input voltage at 3V (rms value). But, on increasing the frequency(say, from 100Hz), the input voltage keeps dropping till I reach the resonant frequency (approx 2KHz)and then increase on increasing the frequency further.
[image]
 For example: At 100 Hz, Vi=3V;
             At 2000Hz, Vi=2.2V;
             At 10KHz,  Vi=2.4V

Is something wrong with the circuit? What should be done to stabilise the input voltage,Vi?

Comment: Are you sure you are taking the voltage output from across R and not from LC ? Taking the output across LC would give you what you are measuring right now (band stop)

Comment: Where is the oscilloscope ground clip placed?

Comment: @efox29: No,I am measuring the input voltage across Vi.

Comment: @Sredni Vashtar: Exactly as is shown in the figure

Comment: Are you using single ended probes ? Is your voltage source single ended as well ?

Comment: Your function generator most likely has an output impedance of 50 ohms.  At resonance the LC will look like a short and then the only load on the generator will be you 100 ohms and the resistance of the inductor.  Does that help?

Comment: What voltmeter are you using?  Have you checked that it can work from 100Hz to 10kHz?

Comment: If you're doing an experiment and must keep the input at 3V, you will have to adjust it manually after each frequency change. The impedance of the circuit changes as the frequency is varied.

Comment: @George Herold: well,yes. But this experiment needs to be done with a constant input voltage, Vi. So, I need to find out how to stabilise the voltage so that it does not fluctuate with increasing frequency.

Comment: @Chu: Could you tell me the relation between the impedance and the frequency? is it becaude Xc=1/wC and XL=wL? Also please tell me if it is possible to get a stable input voltage, Vi for changing frequency?

Comment: @efox29: yes, i am using single ended probes

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat: I am using a DSO to measure the values.

Comment: measure your voltage at intervals of 500 Hz from 1 kHz to 10 kHz and then plot the curve voltage vs frequency. If the curve is like the attenuation in my post below, then you have two solutions: 1 - you find an IDEAL generator with ZERO internal resistance (Sorry, you will not find one) ; 2 - you crank up (and down) the voltage of your generator at every frequency in order to have 3 volts at the series' ends.

Answer (score 1):

Most signal generators have an output impedance set to usually 50 ohms. Some can be set to 600 ohms and some can be set to zero ohms although those set to zero ohms will not be able to supply amps of signal rather they will limit in some haphazard way.

At resonance, the impedance of L+C+R will be R because Xc and Xl are identical |impedances| but of opposite polarity. Net impedance is R: -

[image]
[image]

R then loads the output of the signal generator and you get full signal at low and high frequencies and some fraction of the signal at resonance.

Comment: This makes sense.But, what can be done to improve on the stability of the input voltage,Vi of the generator? Or,like Chu said, does it need to be varied everytime I vary the frequency?

Comment: Use a power amplifier (to buffer the sig gen output) that can handle impedances lower than 100 ohms without dipping the output. Alternatively load the output of the signal generator with 1 ohm and work with much smaller signals. The net effect of the 100 ohm paralleling with the 1 ohm is barely noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

To complement the other answer and comments with some graphs - computed with the actual values of your parameters, here's the impedance of your series RLC circuit, shown on a log-log plot (Log |Z| vs Log f)

[image: Log10 Impedance of RLC series circuit vs Log10 frequency]

Note that the minimum value is 10^2 = 100 ohm at 10^3.4 = 2.5 kHz, the resonant frequency of the circuit.

Your signal generator will therefore see a load variable in frequency. Assuming you have an ideal generator with a 50 ohm series resistance, you are basically facing a voltage divider that will let you have only a fraction of the nominal Vin at the signal generator's output.
This is how much the attenuation of said divider varies with frequency (linear scales, frequency in hertz)

[image: voltage divider attenuation vs frequency in Hz]

And you should be able to replicate that graph, provided your instrument is capable of giving you true RMS values over the whole range of frequencies. Please do notice that this graph is not compatible with the values you reported. To have 2.4 V at 10 kHz, the internal resistance of the generator should be only 2.5 ohms. Either you gave roughly representative values, or your instruments are lying to you (maybe they are not capable of going up to 10 KHz, maybe they are not measuring true RMS, maybe--- something else, who knows, tolerance in your components - the resonant frequency maybe higher than the nominal 2.5 kHz value or the phase of the load impedance is playing tricks on the generator...).

Answer (score 0):

Your 10KHz audio oscillator is not capable of driving the load.

Resistance has nothing to do with resonant frequency, but it does determine the current which flows at resonance.

At resonant frequency, \$X_L = X_C\$, so \$Z = \sqrt{R^2 + (X_L - X_C)^2} =  R\$.  This means \$I_{MAX} = \frac {3V}{100\Omega} = 30mA\$.

It appears your audio oscillator cannot drive a 30mA load.  Decrease your resistance or even remove it.

This fits with the characteristics you are observing.  Below resonant frequency, circuit impedance is capacitive (\$X_L < X_C\$).  Above, inductive (\$X_L >= X_C\$).  As you approach resonant frequency, from either direction, circuit is becoming resistive.  Oscillator is not capable of 30mA, so it puts out what it can.

[image: Series RLC I vs f graph]